# Issues creating/using a simple U.S. to Metric converter. (HTML/JavaScript) Function is not firing

Tags: javascript, html

All this program should/needs to do is do simple conversions between US & Metric, however, for some reason it is resisting every effort I have made to make it work. From what I can tell my script is not firing, I have worked relentlessly to fix it but my lack of experience with JS has made it an uphill battle. My HTML and JS **appear** to be in good order, so it must be my understanding of what I've written that is failing me. 
*The values for calculation come straight from Google, so they should be solid.*

```js
function calc()
{
 var h;
    var ee = isNaN(document.getElementById("number")).value;
    if (ee == "true")
    {
        document.writeln("Please use only numerical keys I.E 128");
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("us").value == 1)
    {if (document.getElementById("met").value == 4)
    {
        h = (document.getElementById("number").value * 453.592;
        document.writeln(document.getElementById("number").value + " pounds is" + h + "grams.");
    }
    else
        document.writeln("This is not a valid conversion!")
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("us").value == 2)
    {if (document.getElementById("met").value == 5)
    {
        h = (document.getElementById("number").value * 0.946353;
        document.writeln(document.getElementById("number").value + " liters is" + h + "quarts.");
    }
    else
        document.writeln("This is not a valid conversion!");
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("us").value == 3)
    {if (document.getElementById("met").value == 6)
    {
        h = (document.getElementById("number").value * 2.54;
        document.writeln(document.getElementById("number").value + " inches is" + h + "centimeters.");
    }
    else
        document.writeln("This is not a valid conversion!");
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>U.S. to Metric Converter</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="conversion.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="number">
        <select name="U.S." id="us">
            <option value="1">Pound(s)</option>
            <option value="2">Quart(s)</option>
            <option value="3">Inch(es)</option>
        </select>
        to
        <select name="Metric" id="met">
            <option value="4">Gram(s)</option>
            <option value="5">Liter(s)</option>
            <option value="6">Centimeter(s)</option>
        </select>
        </form>
    <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="calc()">Convert!</button>
    <div id ="hello"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please be ruthless with me if I am being a complete idiot somewhere in here, my main priority is getting this working but a better understanding of where I am failing is definitely important.

Comment: My problem is solved. Mainly I am an idiot and forgot to copy changes from JSHint made hours ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look closely on this line:

```
h = (document.getElementById("number").value * 453.592;
```

There is an unnecessary `(`. Get rid of that in all places where you have this code and your code will work.

**Working Code Snippet:**

```js
function calc()
{
 var h;
    var ee = isNaN(document.getElementById("number")).value;
    if (ee == "true")
    {
        document.writeln("Please use only numerical keys I.E 128");
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("us").value == 1)
    {if (document.getElementById("met").value == 4)
    {
        h = document.getElementById("number").value * 453.592;
        document.writeln(document.getElementById("number").value + " pounds is" + h + "grams.");
    }
    else
        document.writeln("This is not a valid conversion!")
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("us").value == 2)
    {if (document.getElementById("met").value == 5)
    {
        h = document.getElementById("number").value * 0.946353;
        document.writeln(document.getElementById("number").value + " liters is" + h + "quarts.");
    }
    else
        document.writeln("This is not a valid conversion!");
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("us").value == 3)
    {if (document.getElementById("met").value == 6)
    {
        h = document.getElementById("number").value * 2.54;
        document.writeln(document.getElementById("number").value + " inches is" + h + "centimeters.");
    }
    else
        document.writeln("This is not a valid conversion!");
    }

}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>U.S. to Metric Converter</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="conversion.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="number">
        <select name="U.S." id="us">
            <option value="1">Pound(s)</option>
            <option value="2">Quart(s)</option>
            <option value="3">Inch(es)</option>
        </select>
        to
        <select name="Metric" id="met">
            <option value="4">Gram(s)</option>
            <option value="5">Liter(s)</option>
            <option value="6">Centimeter(s)</option>
        </select>
        </form>
    <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="calc()">Convert!</button>
    <div id ="hello"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you for taking the time to read through this mess. I am truly grateful for your help.

Comment: @NateDiemer No problem. Please **upvote** and mark this answer as accepted if you are satisfied with it. Also, from next time onwards make sure to check the Javascript console for errors and include it in your question here on StackOverflow so we can help better. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript has errors. You are missing the right bracket from a few expressions, e.g.:

```
h = (document.getElementById("number").value * 453.592; <-- add ) before ;
```

I suguest you try using a Javascript debugger such as [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), Chrome or IE Dev Tools, etc.

Have fun!

Comment: I forgot to recopy it after using JSHint, that was my mistake.